# Milestone calculating weekend as a day

Tags: entitlements, casemilestone

I created a entitlement and milestone. Given business hours  as default hours in entitlement process. Created Milestone for 5 days(working hours). I am enabled "Show the time remaining in actual hours, not business hours" checkbox in entitlement settings.

When i created a case, Milestone target time is showing perfectly. but Milestone time it displaying 6 days remaining. Actually it has to be shown 4 days remaning. Milestone timer including weekend also.. How can i rectify this...?

Below is my screenshot of business hours.
[image]

Milestone timer showing 6 days remaining:

[image]

Case Milestone related list

[image]

Comment: Does this have anything to do with [tag:salesforcedx]? I'm not sure it does. Please **[edit]** your question and either remove the tag, or include information that makes the question relevant to Salesforce DX. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in the Entitlement Process definition, include correct Business Hours which you have a defined in Business Hours configuration (excluding weekends).

Secondly, when the milestone is getting created, verify it is attaching to correct Entitlement record.

Also, from the case details, go to Milestones related list and check the correct business hours definition.

Comment: I am excluded weekends, milestone attaching correct entitlement record and i was created default business hours same attaching to milestone that we can see related list. I am attaching the business hours screenshot in the question.

Comment: It is showing actual hours because you have selected actual hours for displaying. If you uncheck this checkbox and create a new record it will show in business hours.

Comment: In business hours it showing 1d Remaining...